# php unable to connect to MySQL via SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, php, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have executed both commands via SSH with no error and than when I try to connect to the MySQL server via SSH tunnel I get no results even if I do a simple query like `select * from table`.

I get no errors when I access the php script in live site.

I get this error:  `mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Operation timed out` when I access the php script hosted locally.

Both of them connect to the remote MySQL server of course. I have Apache and MySQL installed locally  if that changes something.

Everything works fine when I connect via MySQL workbench.

I have also commented this line in `my.cnf`: `#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

`ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 root@server_ip`

`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u root -p database_name`

//php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "root", "database_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [`mysqli` constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) accepts 5th optional argumen specifying port. You should use

   ```
   $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "database_name", "3307");
   ```

instead.

2. Did you verify you can connect to the port from the other host? Mysql is usually using unix domain socket instead of port (which you can forward too).

   ```
   ssh -fNg -L /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock root@server_ip
   ```

Comment: I get this error when I run the second command. `Bad local forwarding specification '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`